# How to access the events in iCalendar in Swift?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am learning Swift and trying to access the the events in `iCalendar` via `EventKit`.

In Objective-C, it works like this:

```
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

In Swift from the document:

**eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(entityType: EKEntityType>, **completion: EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler!**)**

What is "***completion:EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler***" and what should I put in here?

Comment: is it javascript, objC or swift then. I think swift... ;) -- also xcode is unrelated as it is an IDE only

Answer (score 0):

⌘-Click on `EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler` (or any unknown type), and Xcode will jump to its definition:

```
typealias EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler = (Bool, NSError!) -> Void
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how it works  :)

```
eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent) {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError!) in
        println("Got permission = \(success); error = \(error)")
}
```

PS: need to import EventKitUI